# Intermittent turn on fault with laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I have a PCSpecialist laptop (custom built/cheap chinese barebone parts). The laptop is three years old and has been used for fairly intensive gaming without 'good' cooling.

The laptop has an intermittent turn on fault. Sometimes it turns on, sometimes it doesn't.

If I press the power-on button, the power LED turns from amber to green, but the hard drive LED does not turn on and the backlit power-on button does not turn on. The screen does not have any backlighting and the computer does not boot. There are no fan noises. It's as if the motherboard does not recieve power to any critical voltage rails, only whatever rail the power LED is attached to. I have tried a different battery and a different power supply. Neither of these have any effect.

Occasionally, it will cycle: turning on and off for some period of time and I'll wake up to the laptop being on (this takes hours sometimes). I'm currently assuming that this is a motherboard fault, but want to know if there's anything I should try.

I have replaced the CMOS battery, reset BIOS, reseated RAM, repasted CPU, cleaned fans, heated certain areas of the motherboard (CPU/GPU/capacitors) etc. None of this has any effect.

Comment: I think the question is probably too broad as there are a number of things it could be. Have you verified that the power supply is working? Also, have you tried removing the battery in case it is faulty?

Comment: I have tried a different battery and a different power supply.

Comment: 3 years is about the life expectancy of a laptop. Probably best to get a new reliable one if this one has power issues.

Comment: @SirAdelaide relatively happy to get a new one (although I hate to sink money into laptops and not desktops). It's still a pretty powerful machine though, i7-4710MQ, 8 GB, GTX 850M, 120GB SSD, etc. Shame to let it die completely without attempting to fix it.

Comment: @lmsavk: Check the exact date you bought the laptop as PCS standard warranty is 3 years. In theory they would only cover the labour costs but it's possible they won't need to replace anything expensive.

Comment: @JamesP Thanks. Unfortunately, the labour warranty ended two months ago. The replacement part (mobo) is said to be £191 with £35 an hour labour charge and £35 postage. For £261 (min) I might as well buy a £600 machine with a new warranty.